# Grouping Items based on line item number and above value

Tags: sql, row, grouping

Helo, i have a case, below i have a Transacation Table in SQL, that the combo header have sale price and the item of that combo menu is 0 price.

```
Lineitem |  ItemCode  | Item Desc               | sale price |
 1       |   CB1      |     COMBO HEADER MENU1  |  5000      |
 2       |   100      |     Item A              |     0      |
 3       |   101      |     Item B              |     0      |
 4       |   CB2      |     COMBO HEADER MENU2  | 10000      |
 5       |   102      |     Item C              |     0      |
```

Based on that transaction table, if it possible if i would like to grouping the data as below? the items are grouping based on the above combo header that have sale price.
Output :

```
ItemCode   |    Item Desc           | Group |
 CB1       | COMBO HEADER MENU1     | 1     |
 100       | Item A                 | 1     |
 101       | Item B                 | 1     |
 CB2       | COMBO HEADER MENU2     | 2     |
 102       | Item C                 | 2     |
```

or the output can be as below :

```
ItemCode   |    Item Desc           | Group   |
 CB1       | COMBO HEADER MENU1     | CB1     |
 100       | Item A                 | CB1     |
 101       | Item B                 | CB1     |
 CB2       | COMBO HEADER MENU2     | CB2     |
 102       | Item C                 | CB2     |
```

Thank you.

Comment: that looks more like a poor design choice

Answer (score 0):

You need to use rank function in sql that will help
Or Provide the proper table in the comment and what output you want